# Access Merge Text from Different Rows

Tags: ms-access, text, merge, rows

I have a Access DB with following scheme:

```
+---------+---------+-----------+------------+-------------------------------------------+
| BrandNr |  TextNr |  LangCode |  OngoingNr |                    Text                   |
+---------+---------+-----------+------------+-------------------------------------------+
|       1 | AB      |         1 |          1 | Text beginns here but it doesn't end here |
|       1 | AB      |         1 |          2 | Text isn't finished so need second row    |
|       1 | AC      |         2 |          1 | New text                                  |
|       2 | hg2     |         1 |          1 | New brand new text                        |
+---------+---------+-----------+------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Now I need to merge the text where `BrandNR`, `TextNr` and `LangCode` are the same. The Text should be ordered by the `OngoingNr`.

Some ideas?

Comment: Please use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/  to provide sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will require VBA.

One possible method is to call a VBA function which defines a Static string-type variable that is initialised to an empty string for every new combination of `BrandNR`, `TextNr` and `LangCode`, else concatenated with itself.

- Open the VBA IDE using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
- Insert a new Public Module <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>
- Copy the following basic code into the new Module:

  ```vb
  Function Concat(strInp As String, lngOrd As Long) As String
      Static strTmp As String
      If lngOrd = 1 Then strTmp = strInp Else strTmp = strTmp & " " & strInp
      Concat = strTmp
  End Function
  ```
- In MS Access, create a new query with the following SQL, changing `MyTable` to the name of your table:

  ```sql
  select q.BrandNr, q.TextNr, q.LangCode, Concat(q.Text,q.OngoingNr) as Merged
  from
  (
      select t.* from MyTable t 
      order by t.BrandNr, t.TextNr, t.LangCode, t.OngoingNr
  ) q
  ```